# Why is iTunes displaying random junk characters when I try to verify my billing information?

Tags: itunes, itunes-store, billing

I get garbled/garbage characters (weird font?) when I try to manage payment methods (I can't get past this screen to purchase a song*):

[image]

I also got this screen at one point trying to open an apple music link:

[image]

Using latest iTunes app from Microsoft store on Windows 10.

"For you" | "Try it now" also shows junk.

(*) Eventually I was able to purchase a song by guessing what the various fields/buttons were supposed to be. But obviously something very wrong. And yes, have rebooted etc. etc.

At least one other user has reported this: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8066958, however the suggestion (starting iTunes in safe mode) didn't help.

Comment: For whatever reason, iTunes Store is trying to output foreign characters that your computer cannot understand (possible wrong encoding).  I don't know how to fix this, however

Comment: It doesn't just look like an encoding problem, but I can't copy and paste the text to try to convert it. The kerning looks all wrong too.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer: delete any font on your system based on "Helvetica"!
Definitely confirmed this caused the issue - moved HelveticaNeue_0.ttf from the Fonts directory, everything displayed fine, moved it back, display messed up again.